# Node - Fails to run Webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I'm bundling my app using webpack and I'm making sure to specify the target to "node" (otherwise the webpack build fails).

With my current configuration the build is successful, but when I try to run it using node I'm getting an error:

> C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\myproject\dist\app.js:20 /******/
>   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports,
>   **webpack_require**);
>                                             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

It refers to a line inside of the webpackBootstrap function injected into the beginning of app.js. It feels as though node is not compatible with Webpack, even though from what I understood it should be.

I doubt it's relevant to the issue, but in order for you to have the full picture:

I'm transpiling ts and having each file from src exported as a separate chunk into dist instead of bundling everything together, in order to dynamically import files on demand at runtime.

For instance:

- src/app.ts
- src/compA.ts
- src/compB.ts

will become:

- dist/app.js
- dist/compA.js
- dist/compB.js

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');
const glob = require('glob');

let entry = {};

glob.sync('./src/**/*.*').forEach(component => {
    let name = component.match(/.*\/(.*)\..*/)[1];

    entry[name] = component;
});

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry,
    target: 'node',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new CheckerPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        filename: (chunkData) => {
            let name = chunkData.chunk.name;
            let src = chunkData.chunk.entryModule.id;

            let path = src.split('/');
            let dir = path[path.length -2];
            let pathPrefix = dir !== 'src' ? dir + '/' : '';

            return pathPrefix + name + '.js';
        },
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I needed to include node externals in the config.

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    app: ["./back.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build"),
    filename: "bundle-back.js"
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};
```

https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back-end-b95f1b429810